# What are the subject and verb pairs in the sentence given

Tags: verb-agreement

"New York once had two competing political parties, which provided checks on extreme populist ideas."

Per my conclusion i happened to identify the following pairs: S1:New York, V1:had ; S2: which, V2: Checks.
Was confused because "provided" seemed to be the verb to me in the latter part of the sentence.

Comment: Yes, *provided* is the verb and *checks* the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With respect to the first part of the sentence you are correct. However, on the second part, you are mistaken. "Checks" here is a noun, and the verb is indeed "provided". [According to M-W:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/check) one of the meanings of "check", as used here is:

> "**check**" *noun*
>
> 3: one that arrests, limits, or restrains : RESTRAINT

The two parties, of opposing political policies, placed a restraint so that the more extreme ideas did not prevail. No doubt it is an allusion to a common phrase in American politics of "checks and balances", which refers to the different parts of government keeping the others within, preventing one from having excessive amounts of power.